# linked list head doesn't point head but instead end

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

My linked list head supposed to show first entry in each linked list of for iteration. But it always shows last element in linked list,i cant figure out why, i assigned to head at beginning without other link list elements , so isnt it supposed to stay that way?

Why my head only shows each iterations last linked element? I suspect it may relate to adress pointing but i thought this stuff was done like this

```
 typedef struct record_s {
        int id;
        char number[NAMELEN];
        struct record_s *next;
    } Record;

typedef struct person_s {
    int id;
    char name[NAMELEN];
    double expenditure;
    Record *numbers;
} Person;

typedef struct people_s {
    Person data[MAXRECORD];
    int size;
} People;
int main(int argc,char **argv){
    FILE *fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
    int i,j,z=0;
    int o;
    int x;
    int ztemp=0;
    char str[NAMELEN];
    char a[NAMELEN];
    char b[NAMELEN];
    char numbers[NAMELEN][NAMELEN];
    People people1;           
    Record *current,*ptr,*head=NULL,*test;
    int bosluk=0;
    char *token;
    int satir=satir_sayisi(argv[1]);
    for(i=0;i<satir+1;i++){
        current=(Record*)malloc(sizeof(Record));
        people1.data[i].numbers=current;                                            
        head=people1.data[i].numbers;

        fscanf(fp,"%d%s%s%lf",&people1.data[i].id,a,b,&people1.data[i].expenditure);
        fgets (str, 60, fp);
        token=strtok(str," ");
        ztemp=0;
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            ptr=(Record*)malloc(sizeof(Record));
            strcpy(numbers[z],token);
            strcpy(current->number,numbers[z]);
            current->id=people1.data[i].id;


            token = strtok (NULL, " ,\n");
            current->next=ptr;
            ptr=current;
            z++;
            ztemp++;
        }
        current->next=NULL;
        people1.data[i].numbers=head;
        test=head;
        while(test!=NULL){
            printf("%d is id, %s is supposedly the number\n",test->id,test->number);
            test=test->next;
        }

        strcat(a," ");
        strcat(a,b);
        strcpy(people1.data[i].name,a);


    }
    for(o=0;o<satir+1;o++){
        x=0;
        x=strcspn(numbers[o],"\n");
        if(x!=0)
            numbers[i][o]='\0';
    }
    people1.size=i;
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: I did though, i cant figure out what am i missing, my head shows same address with current for somehow, actually my all pointers shows same adresses

Comment: 1) `ptr=current;` is wrong.

Comment: Arghh , thank you i was so stupid , it fixed all problem

Comment: Advice: split up your program into functions.

Comment: Thanks though in main program they are, this is just a test code i wrote to correctly implement linked list